# Linear regression coefficient limitation

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, linear-model

I have built a linear model using `lm` in R

```
lm(age ~ sibsp + parch + pclass, trainset)
```

Here `sibsp` is the number of siblings/spouses aboard the Titanic, `parch` is the number of parents/children aboard and `pclass` is the passenger class (1st, 2nd, 3rd). My problem is that when I run a prediction on a x (from a testset) where variable `sibsp > max(sibsb in trainset)` I get a negative prediction for the `age`.

Any idea how I could work around that problem? I thought of limiting any `x$sibsb` to the `max(sibsb in trainset)` in the model but I'm not sure how to implement that in R.
Any comments or other solutions welcome.

Comment: You need to treat `sibsp` and `parch` as factors, not as numeric variables. Split the data into training and test set using stratified randomization to ensure that both sets have the same combinations of all explanatory variables. And don't expect wonders: after all, for each person with a sibling on board, there will be another record in the dataset with *identical* values of all independent variables but with a different age (unless they are twins/triplets etc.)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear regression with upper and/or lower limits in R?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96245/linear-regression-with-upper-and-or-lower-limits-in-r)

Answer (score 6):

There is no obvious work around here except to choose a more appropriate model. Evidently age cannot be negative, so you should choose a nonlinear model or work with transformations or use a generalised linear model with log link.

I don't think your details about `sibsp`, `sibsb`, etc. will make much sense to most readers. Too much depends on what these abbreviations mean (something biological???).

(LATER) `age` is still unexplained, but there are hints that this is an analysis of data on Titanic survivors. I think you need to explain why `age` is considered as a response or outcome variable (sounds bizarre, on the face of it) and why a linear model. If the model makes no sense, tinkering with it is futile.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I'm basically trying to fill up missing values for the age of passsengers in a dataset (positive mnumerical variable).  I thought as a start I could use a linear model for a rough estimation which would improve on just filling up with the median.... I thought about using glm or a transformation but I wanted to find out first if a "truncated " linear model could do the trick.

Comment: That makes more sense, but I doubt a linear model will work well here.